# A question on Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Prove that every subgroup of an Abelian group is Abelian but the converse is not true. I recently stumbled onto this question , but not able to solve it . Please help me out!

Comment: I don't see why the last edit improved the question...

Comment: You tagged "abelian varieties" first! And that is really wrong.

Comment: *Every proper subgroup* should be in the statement.

Answer (score 3):

it is obvious that every subgroup of every abelian group is abelian. for the inverse $S_3$(group of permutations of 3 objects) is not an abelian group but it's subgroups(except $S_3$) are abelian(beacuse subgroups are of order $1$ or $2$ or $3$ that are abelian).

Comment: Another example is the group $Q=\{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\}$ of elementary quaternions, with the property that every proper subgroup is normal, besides being abelian.

Answer (score 2):

let,G be group.h is subgroup of G.
given that G is abelian i.e. ab=ba for all element of G.
let,x,y be any element of H. H is subgroup of G means H is also subset of G.
therefoer x,y are also elt. of G 
therefore xy=yx for all elt. of H
so H is abelian.
For converse look at S3.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_k$ be the group elements of your abelian group $A$. Since all elements of $A$ commute among each other, this includes every subgroup of $A$.

Otherwise there is a subgroup of a non-abelian group $G$, which contains only elements that commute among each other, called the [center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28group_theory%29). This might be trivially the identity element ...

Comment: The centralizer does NOT contain only elements that commute among each other. The centralizer is defined as $C(x)=\{g \in G \mid gx=xg\}$ and may very well be non-abelian. I believe you are mixing the centralizer with the $\textbf{center}$ which is defined as $Z(G)= \{x \in G:\;\forall g\in G\;,\;\, xg=gx\}$.

Comment: @Sodan you are right. I always had a bad feeling about centralizer and now I know why. Thx...